# HiveQL to PySpark - issue with aggregated column in SELECT statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

I have following HQL script which needs to be puti nto pyspark, spark 1.6

```
insert into table db.temp_avg
select
a,
avg(b) ,
c 
from db.temp WHERE flag is not null GROUP BY a, c;
```

I created few versions of spark code, but I'm stuggling how to get this averaged column into select.

Also I found out that groupped data cannot be write this way:

```
df3 = df2.groupBy...
df3.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('db.temp_avg')
```

part of pyspark code:

```
temp_table = sqlContext.table("db.temp")

df = temp_table.select('a', 'avg(b)', 'c', 'flag').toDF('a', 'avg(b)', 'c', 'flag')
df = df.where(['flag'] != 'null'))
# this ofc does not work along with the avg(b)
df2 = df.groupBy('a', 'c')
df3.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('db.temp_avg')
```

Thx for your help.

Correct solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM db.temp_avg").alias("temp")
df = df.select('a', 'b', 'c')\
    .filter(F.col("temp.flag").isNotNULL())\
    .groupby('a', 'c')\
    .agg(F.avg('b').alias("avg_b"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from db.temp_avg")
```

`df = df.select('a',
                b,
               'c')\
       .filter(F.col("flag").isNotNULL())\
       .groupby('a', 'c')\
       .agg(F.avg('b').alias("avg_b"))`

Then you can save the table by 
`df.saveAsTable("tabe_name")`

Comment: Thx a lot. I'm getting error TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable for F.col("flag") ... when I delete isNotNull() function - u"cannot resolve 'flag' given input columns: [a, b, c];"

Comment: So I saved first select as alias df = sqlContext.sql("select * from db.temp_avg").alias("temp") and than used .filter(F.col("temp.flag").isNotNULL())\ ... It worked fine.